# Teamcity reporting tests two times ( default surefire report and juni XML report)

Tags: junit, teamcity

I am using teamcity to execute some automated test using maven.

I have configured junit XML report processing in the build feature, in the test tab now I see results from both junit report and default surefire report.
How to disable these default surefire report or point teamcity to use junit reports.

I tried removing the surefire reports in the artifacts path but somehow teamcity still picks it up and show the test count on test tab of teamcity

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As far as I know, removing report artifact will not work because TeamCity is reading standard output and collects test results from it.